# Python Matplotlib produces larger and blurrier PDF than R

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, pdf, graphics

Consider the following:

1. Plot a histogram using R and save it in PDF:

   ```
    set.seed(42)
    x = c(rnorm(1000, 1, 1), rnorm(1000, 8, 3))
    pdf("Rplot.pdf", width = 10, height = 3.33)
    par(mar = c(4, 5, 0, 0), family = "serif")
    hist(x, breaks = 100, border = NA, col = "gray", 
         xlab = "x", ylab = "Frequency", cex.lab = 2.75, cex.axis = 2,
         main = "", las = 1, xaxt = "n")
    axis(side = 1, at = seq(-2.5, by = 2.5, len = 30), cex.axis = 2)
    dev.off()
   ```
2. Plot a histogram using Python and save it in PDF:

   ```
   import numpy as np
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   np.random.seed(42)
   x = np.concatenate((np.random.normal(1, 1, size = 1000),
      np.random.normal(8, 3, size = 1000)))
   plt.close()
   plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (10, 3.33)
   plt.rcParams["font.family"] = "Times New Roman"
   plt.rcParams["axes.spines.bottom"] = True
   plt.rcParams["axes.spines.left"] = True
   plt.rcParams["axes.spines.top"] = False
   plt.rcParams["axes.spines.right"] = False
   tmp = plt.hist(x, bins = 100, color = 'lightgray')
   plt.xlabel('x', fontsize = 30)
   plt.ylabel('Frequency', fontsize = 30)
   tmp = plt.xticks(fontsize = 25)
   tmp = plt.yticks(fontsize = 25)
   plt.tight_layout()
   plt.savefig("pyPlot.pdf", bbox_inches='tight')
   ```

Not only `pyPlot.pdf` (13KB) is 2.6x the size of `Rplot.pdf` (5KB), but if we compare them in Adobe Reader, `pyPlot.pdf` is also obviously blurrier than `Rplot.pdf`.

Some further investigation shows that, if we save both plots in `.svg`, then they are totally comparable. `pyPlot.pdf` also appears to be a direct clone of `pyPlot.svg` in terms of visual quality.

Is it possible to generate the level of visual quality and file size of `Rplot.pdf` using Matplotlib?

PS: I uploaded the two `.pdf`s here: https://github.com/WhateverLiu/twoImages . Please check the file size and visual quality. Even in Chrome, if you look closely, `Rplot.pdf` prints smoother labels. But the major problem is that `pyPlot.pdf` is 2.5x larger, which really frustrates my work. Is it simply because R performed extra optimization on its graphic device? I don't want to give up on Python yet..

Comment: Can you post the two images? When I run your Python code I get a pdf with a vectorized figure (I can zoom in without any blurriness)

Comment: @BrenerRamos the two pdfs have been uploaded to https://github.com/WhateverLiu/twoImages

Comment: When I open both pdfs on Adobe Reader on my machine, both figures are vectorized. In other words, there is no bluerriness. I am not sure if I am missing something.

Comment: @BrenerRamos Yes they are both vectorized, but fonts in Rplot.pdf is sharper than those in pyPlot.pdf, and Rplot.pdf is only 5KB comparing to pyPlot.pdf's 12KB. I am making large LaTeX documents of numerous of such plots, and Python gives me figures of both lower visual quality and more than twice the size..

Comment: On my viewer both pdfs look sharp.

Comment: @JodyKlymak Both look sharp but which is sharper? The major problem is that Matplotlib produces 2.5x file size, which is killing me..

Comment: The Matplotlib fonts are type 3 instead of TrueType, which perhaps are blurrier on your viewer.  You can force TrueType in Matplotlib `plt.rcParams["pdf.fonttype"] = 42`, but that makes an even larger file because Matplotlib is embedding the font. I assume that R is not embedding the font, which is OK for common fonts, dangerously unportable for less common fonts.  This font overhead is relatively small, and of fixed size -eg more complicated plots will just have the overhead.  If you want to optimize, Ghostscript can strip the embedding.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60076026/reducing-file-sizes-of-pdfs-created-using-matplotlib-by-changing-font-embedding

Comment: @JodyKlymak Please post your comment as an answer if you'd like and I'll accept it