# Large files with different LaTeX fonts in matplolib

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts, latex, pdf-generation

When I change the default font that matplotlib uses via

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('text.latex', preamble=r'\usepackage{lmodern}')
```

the filesize of the generated pdf is about twice as large compared to not using the `lmodern` package (from ~230kb to ~500kb). Any idea why that is, and how to reduce the filesize?

Comment: Comments here seem to answer some of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56974665/using-latex-text-rendering-increases-pdf-output-of-matplotlib-by-a-factor-20-is

Comment: The most direct way to reduce filesize is probably choosing jpg or png during savefig.

Comment: Thanks, that is indeed the underlying issue. The constant offset of a few 100 kbs makes sense.

Comment: I've been able to reduce the filesize by using the PGF backend of matplotlib: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/text/pgf.html . Not sure why this worked, though.

Comment: Interesting. Are you embedding the PGF directly in TeX documents? It could be saving space by not embedding fonts multiple times.

Comment: I haven't tried the direct embedding, yet, since `plt.savefig("figure.pdf", backend='pgf')` actually produces the small pdf file directly.

Answer (score 1):

As [Coeus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10937722/coeus) mentioned in the own comments, the PGF backend yields a smaller PDF size compared to the PDF backend. The reason is that the latter does not embed subsets of fonts. See the [open issue on GitHub](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/127) and [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65365026/2531400) for details.